# MercadoPago Connect: Problemas Obtención credenciales usuario. SSL

Tags: php, mercadopago, ssl

Siguiendo las instrucciones que ofrece MercadoPago, para incorporar "MercadoPago Connect"(PHP). Me da el siguiente error cuando intento obtener las credenciales del usuario con el código de ejemplo, completando la clave secreta, el codigo obtenido y la URI de redirección.
(https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect)

**Código utilizado(PHP):**

```
$mp = new MP("TEST-1638810707895512-111913-d3dde942495aa41fa5b71f41f1348225__LD_LC
__-228899152");

$request = array(
        "uri" => "/oauth/token",
        "data" => array(
             "client_secret" => $mp->get_access_token(),
             "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
             "code" => "AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
             "redirect_uri" => "REDIRECT_URI"
        ),
        "headers" => array(
            "content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ),
        "authenticate" => false
    );
$mp->post($request);
```

**Error obtenido:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message
>   'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)' in
>   /mercadopago/mercadopago.php:508 Stack trace: #0
>   /mercadopago/mercadopago.php(563): MPRestClient::exec(Array) #1
>   /mercadopago/mercadopago.php(357): MPRestClient::post(Array) #2
>   /content/ride.php(27): MP->post(Array) #3 /mercadopago/mercadopago.php
>   on line 508

Alguien sabe que indica la excepción? Cómo puedo hacer para solucionar la misma. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de solucionar tal problema es usar la conexión alternativa por medio de curl.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_secret=TEST-1638810707895512-111913-d3dde942495aa41fa5b71f41f1348225__LD_LC__-228899152&grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

De esta forma se pueden obtener las credenciales necesarias del usuario por el cual operaremos.